# Garbage at compilation and output C++ (Atom/QtCreator)

Tags: c++, macos, qt, gcc, atom-editor

After creating a console application and running it, a lot of garbage appears with the output, such as last login and a strange path to the directory:

> /var/folders/zd/...

If I write separately in the editor, and run it through GCC directly, there is no problem; there is a net output.

To the left of the output under the Atom, right Qt

[image]

Could it be errors in the assembly? And how do I get a clean output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt Creator does not run your application directly, but through a small helper executable `qtcreator_process_stub`. This opens some interprocess communication channels, which enables Qt Creator to e.g. kill your application when you press the stop button, attach a debugger, setup the environment for the application that you set in the run configuration, etc. Unfortunately the command that needs to be run in the terminal application becomes the ugly thing you see, and unfortunately the terminal echos these commands so you actually see them.